# Finding the image ID of a container from within the container

Tags: docker

I've seen some other questions on this, although some are 2+ years old - I'm looking to try to 'validate' the docker image running my code hasn't been extended and messed with.  Does anyone know a way to secure the contents of a container so I can deliver a docker image as a means of delivering a service to a customer - and it will be running in *their* cluster - so I have little to no control on startup, environment, etc....

To me, being able to 'checksum' an image is pretty core to using docker as a means of delivering solutions to 3rd parties.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you push the image to a docker registry and pull the image to run it on their cluster, you can use `docker images --digests` to view the checksum of all your images.

> When pushing or pulling to a 2.0 registry, the push or pull command
>   output includes the image digest. You can pull using a digest value.
>   You can also reference by digest in create, run, and rmi commands, as
>   well as the FROM image reference in a Dockerfile.
>
> Ref:
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-image-digests

Comment: that's true, but doesn't really answer my question of finding the image id from inside the running container - you can get the container id via looking at /proc/self/cgroup - just wish there was the image id in there too - not that I can think of a way to check that id... alternatively, some way of defining a docker image as FINAL would also work...