# In an AWS lambda, how do I access the image_id or tag of the launched container from within it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam

I have an AWS lambda built using SAM. I want to propagate the id (or, if it's easier, the tag) of a lambda's supporting docker image through to the lambda runtime function.

How do I do this?

Note: I do mean image id and **NOT** container id - what you'd see if you called `docker image ls` locally. Getting the container id / hostname is the easy bit :D

I have tried to declare a parameter in the template.yaml and have it picked up as an environment variable that way. I would prefer to define the value at most once within the template.yaml, and preferably have it auto-populated, though I am not aware of best practice there. The aim is to avoid human error. I don't want to pass the value on the command line unless I have to.

If it's too hard to get the image id then as a fallback the `DockerTag` would be fine. Again, I don't want this in multiple places in the template.yaml. Thanks!

Unanswered similar question: [Finding the image ID of a container from within the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396283/finding-the-image-id-of-a-container-from-within-the-container)

Answer (score 0):

The launched image URI is available in the packaged template file after running `sam package`, so it's possible to extract the tag from there.

For example, if using YAML:

```
grep -w ImageUri packaged.yaml | cut -d: -f3
```

This will find the URI in the packaged template (which looks like `ImageUri: 12345.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myrepo:mylambda-123abc-latest`) and grabs the tag, which is after the 2nd `:`.

That said, I don't think it's a great solution. I wish there was a way using the SAM CLI.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I then access the tag from within the launched image?

Comment: Ah wait, I think we both arrived at the same answer. Having packaged, one can deploy and access that tag via a populated ENV. Thanks! I actually went via a file.... ugly I know... :/